# Get payment by transaction ID using PayPal API

Tags: paypal

I have a PayPal transaction ID, but don't know what payment ID is associated with it. The payment was not necessarily created by the REST API. I would like to query for the payment using the transaction ID.

The REST API docs suggest that looking up sales by transaction IDs is [only possible if they were created using the REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-sale) and [don't list any way to retrieve a payment except by its ID](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource).

Is it possible for me to use the API to determine what payment a transaction belongs to?

Comment: Sorry... you are going to be out of luck. The REST APIs rely on internal data structures that are only built for transactions created through those same APIs. Other (non-REST) PayPal transactions are totally invisible to the REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to use the classic API, specifically [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).