# How to get invoice Id using Transaction id in Paypal in php

Tags: php, paypal, invoice

I completed the Paypal payment integration successfully. But I want to get the invoice id. I have only transaction id.

Using this transaction id how to get invoice id from Paypal?

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207824/get-payment-by-transaction-id-using-paypal-api